# Java Collections - Quickest way to find if there is a Common element between two Sets

Tags: java, collections, set, guava, set-intersection

I have two *sets* from Guava `HashMultimap.values()`.

I need to find out if there's an **intersection** of these two *non-empty sets* with the best possible time complexity.

I don't need to know about the common elements, just if there's at least one common element.

I was thinking of using `Sets.intersection()`, but it has time complexity **O(m+n)**. Can we find out whether there's a common element without creating the entire intersection?

Something like (*pseudocode*):

```
set.intersection(set2).any()
```

The data set is pretty big and this operation happens within a loop, and hence performance is paramount.

Answer (score 38):

With the normal JDK, this is just

```
!Collections.disjoint(set1, set2)
```

This bails immediately if an element is found in common.

(Although -- for what it's worth -- `Sets.intersection` is lazier than you realize.  It returns a view in constant time, and its `isEmpty()` method would also bail immediately upon finding the first element in common, so it'd be just as efficient.)

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Collection#retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

> Retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation). In other words, removes
>   from this collection all of its elements that are not contained in the
>   specified collection.

Comment: But this is similar to Sets.intersection() right. This operation still creates the complete intersection.

Comment: @doc_180:- Yes thats right. You may try to go with Louis Wasserman idea. That is what you want probably!!

Comment: I am going to use his idea. Sets.intersection might just work since it is lazy. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the best case time complexity **Ω(1)** with Stream API.

We can create a stream over the elements from the *fist set*, and check each element against the *second set* using [`anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).

```
boolean hasIntersection = set1.stream().anyMatch(set2::contains);
```

Streams are lazy, and `anyMatch()` - is a *short-circuit* terminal operation, which means that after the first element for which the *predicate* passed as argument would be evaluated to `true` the stream would terminate producing the resulting value, and all remained elements would **not** be processed.